# payment method configuration page in admin is not opening magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, payment-methods, system-configuration, maintenance

I am trying to open **configuration > sales > payment methods** but it shows

> Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your
>   request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try
>   again later.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at mysitename.de Port 80

i have tried with this

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and there is also no any **.maintenance.flag** in root or in var directory

how to fix it in magento 2

Comment: Where you unable to open only that particular page or the entire website? Any server error logs?

Comment: particularly this page only and no log

Comment: Have you tried giving write permissions to var, pub and generated foldrers

Comment: yes i have tried

Comment: is there any possibility for any other third party module error?

Comment: Can you please check the server log at var/log/apache2/error_log and magento/var/log/systemlog

Comment: i don't have server access so i can check only  magento/var/log/systemlog.so how can i check var/log/apache2/error_log

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? Do you have root privilege to view the server log files? This error log will be definitely in server log

Answer (score -1):

Try a full clean:

- php bin/magento c:c
- php bin/magento c:f
- rm -rf var/cache/*
- rm -rf var/page_cache/*
- rm -rf generated/*
- rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
- Check for permissions/Give back permissions
- F12 (Developer tools) -> Application -> Clear Storage (tab) -> Clear site data
- On refresh you should be forced to log out -> relog